# Why does my if else statement not work as desired? Problems with input

Tags: java

Why can my code not go on the process of if else statement? it's inputting 3 times and I need only 1 input.

I can't see what's wrong with this code, please help me

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Employee Full name:  ");
        String fn = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Employee Number:  ");
        int en = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the current monthly salary:  ");
        int ms = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the performance rating:  ");
        double pr = input.nextDouble();
        double raise = input.nextDouble();
        double nms = input.nextDouble();
        
        {   
        if(pr == 1){
            System.out.println("EXCELLENT!!");
            raise = ms * .06;
        }
        else if(pr == 2){
            System.out.println("Good!");
            raise = ms * .04;
        }
        else if(pr == 3){
            System.out.println("poor.");
            raise = ms * .015;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("ERROR!!!");
        }
        nms = ms + raise;

        System.out.println(fn);
        System.out.println(en);
        System.out.println(raise);
        System.out.println(nms);
        }
    }   
}
```

OUTPUT:

That's the output

[image]

I really don't know what is wrong

Comment: `double pr = input.nextDouble(); double raise = input.nextDouble(); double nms = input.nextDouble();` <- If you write code that asks the user 3 times for input, then that is what your program will do. If you want those 3 values all assigned to one input just ask for user input once and then just copy the value from the other variables like `double pr = input.nextDouble(); double raise = pr; double nms = pr;`

Comment: owww, thanks about that!! really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner(System.in) uses the buffer to store the input value(s) from begin to the end marked by ENTER (\r\n). As long as you use

```
scaner.nextLine(); // read the whole line and remove ENTER
```

But if you do

```
int ms = input.nextInt();
 System.out.print("Enter the performance rating:  ");
 double pr = input.nextDouble();
```

The pr = input.nextDouble() gets the white space ENTER and that is invalid. You have 2 choices:
either

```
int ms = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

or

```
int ms = input.nextInt();
imput.netxLine(); // jump over ENTER
```